# What does sips --man option do

Tags: terminal, command-line, sips

`sips`, or “scriptable image processing system” is a command-line tool shipping by default with macOS which allows basic image manipulation (think ImageMagick but not as powerful).

I found something odd on it’s `man` page:

```
 --man
       Generate man pages
```

It’s not clear at all why this tool would benefit from a way to generate man pages, nor how the feature works. What does it do and how does one use it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why Apple is distributing the manual inside the application. The syntax `--man` is familiar to users of the Korn shell. It will produce static manuals for certain korn shell builtin commands. To use `--man` with `sips` you could uses the following:

```
sips --man | /usr/bin/groff -Tutf8 -mandoc -c
```

that will produce a static manpage.

Comment: Re your comment about ksh builtins incorporating man pages, you might find this useful. I do.   https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/325#issuecomment-974424976

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

As the man page says: it generates a man page. man pages have a specific format with various text codes to style the data.

It generates a copy of the sips man page.

Comment: I did try it before asking and saw the `sips` man page. But that just seems useless. What’s the point of a flag for generating the codes to your own man page? If it can make other manages, fine, but it’s still not clear how to use it.

Comment: It contains its own documentation.  Why is this a problem?

Comment: It’s not a problem, it’s just odd. Someone went through the trouble of adding the feature and a flag for it, so I expect it to have a *purpose*. That purpose isn’t clear, so I want to understand it. Maybe it’s something I can use. One becomes a better developer by enquiring and understanding past decisions, not by ignoring what eludes us until it breaks.

Comment: Its *purpose* is to be documentation.